# Clang RecursiveASTVisitor warning message?

Tags: c++, objective-c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

When running my RecursiveASTVisitor program on Objective C codes, I keep getting this warning `warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-receiver-is-weak'; did you mean '-Wno-receiver-expr'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]`

But I didn't compile it with warnings enabled or have any warning options within my code.

Where does the error warning come from and how can I disable it?

Comment: Can you post your execution command? using which you run the visitor.

Comment: I didn't pass anything extra in command line currently. My RecursiveASTVisitor is called MyASTChecker, so what I did was to get into `build/bin` folder and run `./MyASTChecker /path/to/sourcefile.m`

Comment: I am sorry, I was hoping to get something there. I won't be able to help you.

Comment: No problem mate, thanks for helping! :)